# Abelian fundamental group: working algebraically

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Here's the premise. Let $X$ be any topological space with distinguished base point $x_0$, and let $f: X \times X \to X$ be a map such that $f(x,x_0) = f(x_0,x) = x$ for all $x \in X$. Then $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is abelian.

I know how to prove this 'directly', that is, construct explicit homotopies to show that composition of homotopy classes of loops commute.
However, it'd be nice to see an 'algebraic' approach, working in the fundamental group itself.
My first thoughts are to consider the pushforward $\phi^*: \pi_1(X \times X, (x_0, x_0)) \to \pi_1(X, x_0)$, and somehow construct an abelian quotient of the domain space.
However I'm not sure exactly how this would work, as I can't see any way to do this. Some hints here would be ideal.

Comment: You are almost there. What you need to show is that the map $\pi_1(X \times X) = \pi_1(X) \times \pi_1(X) \rightarrow \pi_1(X)$ is the same as the group multiplication on $\pi_1(X)$. Then since a map of spaces induces a homomorphism of fundamental groups, we have that the multiplication on $\pi_1(X)$ is actually a group homomorphism. Then you can prove the entirely algebraic fact that a group with its multiplication map a group homomorphism must be abelian.

Comment: Ah I see, after working out I am still not sure about the first part. For the map $f^*$ to be the same as group multiplication, I believe I need more restrictions/definitions of what $f$ is besides just the defining property above. Otherwise how can I show that $f(\gamma_1, \gamma_2)(t) = (\gamma_1 \bullet \gamma_2) (t)$?

Comment: What I could do was opposite. I could see it algebraically but couldn't prove it directly.:-)

Comment: @Qizard:  The composition $X\xrightarrow{i} X\times X\xrightarrow{f} X$ with $i(x) = (x,x_0)$ is the identity, and this tells you $f_\ast(a,e) = a$ (where $e$ is the identity in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$.  Likewise, if you replace $i$ with $j(x) = (x_0,x)$....

Comment: One way to show this is using an Eckmann–Hilton argument.

Comment: The geometric fact required to prove the two multiplications are the same is that you can make the first half of your loop the identity and cram the rest of your loop into the second half. This doesn't change the element of the group. You can also make the second half the identity and cram the loop into the first half. Now you should try to do the pointwise multiplication.